# setting true or false in unslider.js

Tags: javascript, jquery

hey guys i have been trying to deconstruct a jquery plugin called Unslider.js . I have worked out most part of it , but have a small difficulty with one lin eof code :

on line 154 of the plugin , there is a condition that does a check using an if condition :

check the plugin line : [line 154](https://github.com/idiot/unslider/blob/master/src/unslider.js#L154)

the condition is as follows :

```
if (_.t) {
    _.stop();
    _.play();
}
```

what the above condition obviously is doing is , checking if _.t is true and if true , it run's the 2 functions listed inside it .

now that was easy to understand , but while going thorugh the plugin code , i nowhere saw the value of _.t being set to true or false , the only other places that _.t gets referred to is on line 193 and line 200 , look below :

Line 193 :

```
_.play = function() {
            _.t = setInterval(function() {   // 193
                _.to(_.i + 1);
            }, _.o.delay | 0);
        };
```

Line 200 :

```
_.stop = function() {
            _.t = clearInterval(_.t);  // line 200
            return _;
        };
```

can somebody point be out where exactly is the value of _.t being set to true or false ? the entire plugin code is linked [here](https://github.com/idiot/unslider/blob/master/src/unslider.js)

Thanks you .

Alexander.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line `_.t = setInterval(…` returns [intervalID](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setInterval), which is not undefined, and the line:

```
 _.t = clearInterval(_.t);
```

makes `t` in `_.t` undefined, as return value of [clearInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.clearInterval) is undefined, so:

```
if (_.t) {
    _.stop();
    _.play();
}
```

checks to see if `_.t` is not undefined and proceeds further. Here `this` is represented as `_`

Comment: Thanks for ur answer , are u sure though ? , yes i know _ mean this .

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik yes, i'm sure of it.. :)

Comment: just an added Question , so you are basically saying that _.stop() turns _.t to false and _.play() turns _.t to true ?

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik yes, _stop turns the value of 't' to undefined, whereas _play() turns value of 't' to some defined value...!